# Search function to look up name of objects in JSON

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, dom

JSON file:

```
[
    {
            "destination": "Hawaii",
            "Country": "U.S.A",
            "description": "...etc, etc",
            "images": {
                "image": [
                    "hawaii1.jpg",
                    "hawaii2.jpg",
                    "hawaii3.jpg",
                    "hawaii4.jpg"
                ]
            }
        }, 
    ***about 5 more destinations continuing on***
```

.JS:

```
function searchBar() {

   var input = document.getElementById('searchbox').value;
   var name = ["Hawaii", "London", "Bangkok", "Sydney", "Vegas", "Miami"];
   var ul = document.getElementById("cities");  //ul in markup where li of destinations is displayed


   //I know i need to do an if statement in a for loop, just not sure how.
   for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++){

       if(input == name){
        li[i].style.display = "";
       } else{
        li[i].style.display = "none";
       }

    }
}
```

I want to have it so the search bar in my HTML will display that destination when the NAME OR COUNTRY is typed in.   Not sure how to approach this. I was thinking making names into an array then comparing that with the 'searchbox' value??

The JSON objects have been appended to h2 elements in a different function, which was then appended into a li element.
Sorry, I left out a lot of code, please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

In order to listen to `input` events you need to add a listener to it, then you can listen for `keyup` for example. Once you know someone typed something, then you want to go through the data that you have and check if it matches any of the object's `destination` or `Country` values.

If that's the case, then just append a list item to the current unordered list, something likke:

```js
let data = [{
  destination: "Hawaii",
  Country: "U.S.A",
  description: "...etc, etc",
  images: {
    image: ["hawaii1.jpg", "hawaii2.jpg", "hawaii3.jpg", "hawaii4.jpg"],
  },
}, ];

var input = document.getElementById("searchbox");
// var name = ["Hawaii", "London", "Bangkok", "Sydney", "Vegas", "Miami"];
var ul = document.getElementById("cities"); //ul in markup where li of destinations is displayed

input.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  let typed = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
  for (let o of data) {
    if (
      typed === o.destination.toUpperCase() ||
      typed === o.Country.toUpperCase()
    ) {
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerText = JSON.stringify(o);
      ul.append(li);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<p>Type <code>hawaii</code></p>
<input type="text" id="searchbox" />
<ul id="cities"></ul>
```

The solution above has a few issues, for example, it doesn't clear the `ul` if the input is cleared or it keeps appending new objects if you type the same country/destination again. Those are relatively easy fixes which I'll leave for you, but overall you'd want something along those lines.