# How to make search function for JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom

.JSON file:

```
[
    {
            "destination": "Hawaii",
            "description": "...etc, etc",
            "images": {
                "image": [
                    "hawaii1.jpg",
                    "hawaii2.jpg",
                ]
            }
        }, 
    ***about 5 more destinations continuing on***
```

.Javascript:

```
function searchbar() {

    const input = document.getElementById("searchbox").value;

    var array = [];

    fetch('trip.json')
        .then(function(result){
         return result.json();
        })

        .then(function(data){
            for (let i =0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                if (data[i].destination == input){
                    array.push(data[i]);
                }
            }
        document.getElementById('ul').remove();
        createtripData(array);
        });
}
```

- I want my code to display the correct destination when the name is inputted in my 'searchbar' in HTML.
- For each JSON element, I created an "li" element and appended it to the "li" (in a previous function, createTrip(tripData).
- If an incorrect destination is inputted, then " "Name" cannot be found" in an li element should be displayed.

Am i on the right track? Thank you!!

Comment: There is only one [*JSON object*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-json-object). Your data is formatted as JSON, it's parsed essentially as an object literal. This seems more like a code review question, do you have a specific issue you want help with?

Comment: theres a note at the bottom of my JSON file saying theres about 5 more objects, with essentially the same info "destination, country, etc". 
Im trying to creat a function search that will output the city when searched. my code is not working

Comment: Ok, so you need to include sample input, expected output, actual output and any error messages plus a description of what you think is going wrong. Best to post the code as a minimal runnable snippet, so trim it down to the minimum required to demonstrate the issue (e.g. you might want to put stubs for fetch, createtripData, etc. that just return fixed values).

Comment: There's an answer here that might be useful given that it's the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61240373/search-function-to-look-up-name-of-objects-in-json/61240675#61240675